# SQFlite does not find existing Table

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am trying to query threw all the Data in my Database where the name of the Table is 'links', but i always get this Error:

```dart
W/e.dsa_regelwik( 4691): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/e.dsa_regelwik( 4691): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/e.dsa_regelwik( 4691): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/e.dsa_regelwik( 4691): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/SQLiteLog( 4691): (1) no such table: links
```

This is my Helper class with the query-function:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'DSA_Database.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = join(databasesPath, 'DSA_Database.db');
    await deleteDatabase(path);

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join('assets', 'DSA_Database.db'));
    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  }

  Future<List<Titles>> getTitles() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var titles = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM links');
    List<Titles> titlesList =
        titles.isNotEmpty
            ? titles.map((e) => Titles.fromMap(e)).toList()
            : [];
    return titlesList;
  }
}
```

I am trying to fix that Error since 5 days now, but i can't find any solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to delete the database while opening it (i.e. during onCreate) which won't work because the database is already open at this point. You should move what you are currently doing in `_onCreate` before calling `openDatabase`.

See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md for an example on how to open an asset database.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped!
Now it detects the DB but i now get this Error:
```E/SQLiteLog(16273): (11) database corruption at line 62361 of [68b898381a]
E/SQLiteLog(16273): (11) statement aborts at 3: [] database disk image is malformed
E/SQLiteLog(16273): (11) database disk image is malformed
```

Comment: Hard to tell, it seems your db is corrupted you can check it using the sqlite3 command tool on your desktop (see https://support.storj.io/hc/en-us/articles/360029309111-How-to-fix-a-database-disk-image-is-malformed- - make sure that the version is v3.25.2 or later, otherwise the check will not work correctly): 
`sqlite3 --version ; sqlite3 <your_db_file> "PRAGMA integrity_check; "`